# java web app - creating data object class

Tags: java, web-applications

I am using a web application to retrieve all records from a table in MySQL and display the results in the browser (JSP page).

I used a resultSet to obtain the info from the table and need an object class to store the result before adding it to the list.

My servlet looks like this:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

   response.setContentType("text/html");

   try{
       Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
       Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:mysql://126.32.3.11:3306/test", "root", "root");
       String sql ="Select * from filequeue;";
       statement = conn.createStatement();
       ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);

       Wb wb= null;

       while(resultSet.next()){

           wb=new Wb();
           // display each record
           wb.setUniqueId(resultSet.getString("UniqueID"));
           wb.setFilePath(resultSet.getString("FilePath"));
           wb.setStatus(resultSet.getString("Status"));
           wb.setDate(resultSet.getString("DateTime"));
           wb.setError(resultSet.getString("Error"));
           // add the records to a list to display on jsp
           list.add(resultSet);
       }

       resultSet.close();
       statement.close();
       conn.close();
       RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");
       request.setAttribute("queryResults",list);
       dispatcher.forward(request,response);

   } catch (Exception e) {
       System.out.println(e);
   }
```

My WB class:

```
public class Wb {

    public void setUniqueId(String id){
        id =
    }

}
```

Note: WB class is not completed yet

In my WB class, I am stuck on how to proceed to pass the parameters value to the servlet.

Apart from that, am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can create pojo Wb.java , in which you can define all properties and their getter setters

```
private String UniqueId;
private String FilePath;
private String Status;
private String Date;
private String Error;
public String getUniqueId() {
    return UniqueId;
}
public void setUniqueId(String uniqueId) {
    UniqueId = uniqueId;
}
public String getFilePath() {
    return FilePath;
}
public void setFilePath(String filePath) {
    FilePath = filePath;
}
public String getStatus() {
    return Status;
}
public void setStatus(String status) {
    Status = status;
}
public String getDate() {
    return Date;
}
public void setDate(String date) {
    Date = date;
}
public String getError() {
    return Error;
}
public void setError(String error) {
    Error = error;
}
```

Then store all results in List and forward it to index.jsp as below

```
  List<Wb> list=new ArrayList<Wb>(); 

  while(resultSet.next()){

     wb=new Wb();
 // display each record
  wb.setUniqueId(resultSet.getString("UniqueID"));
   wb.setFilePath(resultSet.getString("FilePath"));
   wb.setStatus(resultSet.getString("Status"));
   wb.setDate(resultSet.getString("DateTime"));
    wb.setError(resultSet.getString("Error"));
    // add the records to a list to display on jsp
     list.add(wb);
 }
 resultSet.close();
 statement.close();
 conn.close();
 RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");
 request.setAttribute("queryResults",list);
 dispatcher.forward(request,response);
```

Iterate the list on JSP to show the contain using jstl or scriptlet.